# Dynamically show GMap markers according location and zoom level of user

Tags: jquery, performance, google-maps

Good day !

Have a task and need a good idea or solution how to implement that. 
We have about 90k markers in database and want to show this on Google maps. It's not good to show all markers at page load, due it's overload page and it'll be impossible to use website. So the idea it to make load some parts of markers about 300 markers according user Google map location and zoom level. When user move Google map location to another place, script will load new portion of markers and will show them on the map.

At first question, i kindly ask to give advice how to properly store values of latitude and longitude in database for speed search and AJAX requests to backend. Our structure of database is following:

| **ID**    | **post_title**  |  **Latitude** | **Longitude**. |

| 974411 |  Title of house |    25.058746   | 55.209389

Please tell, whether this table structure is good for speed search and compare of latitude and longitude. If index is needed to be placed at columns of this table ?
Next thing is how to count the nearby markers according center of users Google map position. And make it run fast with previous database structure:

[image]

[Gif to demonstration of how this should work (13Mb GIF)](http://i.giphy.com/3o85xHB4iNkCkFjwas.gif)

And last problem is how to how dynamically markers, when user change zoom level. How to show markers from places, that near the edge of the map. Showing markers according some distance, for example, 20-25km is not enough, due user can zoom out high and this algorithm will be not enough to show markers, that placed on much more bigger distance, than 20-25km.

Thanks !

Comment: This are several questions, i suggest you of spilt them in single question

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks friend, i suppose, this question has one side and needed algorithm. No split needed.

Comment: Nice, this site contains info you are looking for [**link**](https://developers.google.com/maps/). Enjoy learning.

Comment: @so_jin_ee Sorry friend, this website doesn't have information how to store data in database and how to operate about 90k-100k markers for front-end

Comment: So it sounds more like a database question... not google-maps feature specific...

Comment: To show markers within a given radius, you will want to run a query to find lat/lng points where distance from current center to given lat/lng < a constant defined by zoom level, and then push them on your map for users to see. Storing lat/lng in a database really depends on what database you use... lat/lng is just two strings... so basically you would want to do an insert to your database.

Comment: Or you can try [**cluster**](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) as another option if there's too many markers.

Comment: @so_jin_ee thank you, but your comments make no sense to this question. Sorry.